# The way to indicate that new messages are present (mutt)

Tags: email, email-client, mutt, dotfiles

So the basic problem I want to discuss, is there a way to indicate that new messages were got into the mail box?

What I mean, currently I have about ~8 separate folders managed by sieve, I do not read some of them for a long time, so I have dozen number of unread messages. Of course I can not remember exact number to  make sure that changes have been made to the folder, as a result, I still have *some* unread messages, but do not understand if new ones had been added or not. (For example thunderbird has asterisks for that).

Answer (score 1):

From the mutt documentation, you can control if unread messages are marked as old (with an **O** instead of an **N** marker) when you exit the program:

> 3.122. mark_old
>
> Type: boolean Default: yes
>
> Controls whether or not mutt marks new unread messages as old if you
>   exit a mailbox without reading them. With this option set, the next
>   time you start mutt, the messages will show up with an “O” next to
>   them in the index menu, indicating that they are old.